# Using jQuery to Call ASP.NET AJAX Page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to call ajax function with the jQuery. Here is my sample coding

```
  <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            if ($("#txtUserName").val() == '')
                alert("Please enter the UserName");
            else    
                sendData($("#txtUserName").val());
        });

        function sendData(sUserName) {
            debugger

            var loc = window.location.href;
            loc = (loc.substr(loc.length - 1, 1) == "/") ? loc + "Recipe3.aspx" : loc;
           ' $.ajax({
             debugger
                type: "POST",
                url: loc + "/CheckUserName",
                data: '{"sUserName":"' + sUserName + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    if (msg.d)
                        alert("The User Name is valid");
                    else
                        alert("The User Name is invalid")
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("An unexpected error has occurred during processing.");
                }
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

What does this mean: `loc = (loc.substr(loc.length - 1, 1) == "/") ? loc + "Recipe3.aspx" : loc;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, user can access the page with "http://www.yourDomain.com/someDir/", **or** with "http://www.yourDomain.com/someDir/Recipe3.aspx".

the server (i guess iis) take charge of calling recipe3.aspx when the "http://www.yourDomain.com/someDir/".

However, the ajax call url is "http://www.yourDomain.com/someDir/recipe3.aspx/CheckUserName", not "http://www.yourDomain.com/someDir//CheckUserName".

this if statement makes sure the correct ajax url target is the good one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means if the last character of loc is "/", append "Recipe3.aspx".